# Which highchart should i used to represent below data?

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts, highcharts

I have following data in table and I want to display in graph can you please suggest which graph should i choose to represent below data. I want to use **highchart.**

```
Ref No  Available Date  Report Date     Competitor  
214     24-02-2017      17-02-2017      ABC
337     24-02-2017      18-01-2017      ABC
337     10-02-2017      18-01-2017      XYZ
322     24-01-2017      13-01-2017      XYZ  
337     10-02-2017      12-01-2017      DEF
322     24-01-2017      10-01-2017      ABC
337     10-02-2017      10-01-2017      DEF
214     24-01-2017      03-01-2017      XYZ
```

I want to show in graph particular competitor has how many Ref No. on perticular month (Report Date)
Let Say for example `ABC` has `3 Ref No. (322,337,214)` from those month of `January` has `2 (322,337)`  month of `February` has `1 (214)`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It only depends on what you want to see. Ask whomever needs to understand the data.

Comment: @YuryFedorov please check updated question.

Comment: Whatever way you choose to show the data, you'll first have to process the data to develop the actual counts that you are looking for. From there, how to display it still depends on a number of factors, but is not a programming question appropriate for SO.  Try something like this forum: http://www.perceptualedge.com/discussion.htm